# Elastic Search server searching remain continious while indexing the data into it

Tags: elasticsearch, search

How to serve search or query operation uninterrupted from a elastic server while we index/re-index the data into that particular elastic search server at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at using aliases:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html

Essentially you create new index with a unique name, and swap the alias out with the old index, in one atomic step